# How to set page layout in latex?

Tags: margins, paragraphs, paper-size

I need to set page layout in latex but the instructions I've got are for word.

The instructions I have got are:
Page layout: Normal

*Margins:
Top:1.0 cm
Left: 1.0 cm
Bottom: 1.0 cm
Right: 1.0 cm
Gutter: 0.0 cm
Gutter position: Left

*Paper:
A4
Width: 8.27 cm
Height: 11.69 cm

*Layout:
Header:0.49 cm
Footer: 0.49 cm

*Paragraph:
Spacing-
Before: 6pt
After: 0pt
Line Spacing: Single

Comment: See `geometry` package. In its documentation you will find how to do this on the simple and clear way.  Manual on page 3 contain  graphic presentation how to set-up page layout.

Comment: Thank you Žarko.